# How do I get Devise and JWT to work with my Versioned API Rails Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, jwt

I have a rails API using Devise. When you hit the POST /login endpoint, it logs the user in and provides a JWT. This was all working fine until I recently moved to namespace my controllers with a version. This is what my sessions#create method looks like:

```
def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)

    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?

    render json: current_user
  end
```

When making a login request from the front end, this what my parameters look like:

```
{
    user: {
        email: 'john@gmail.com',
        password: 'password'
    }
}
```

This was working before, but now that I've migrated to a Api::V1 namespace for my sessions controller, it requires the front end to submit credentials under :api_v1_user instead of :user.

Is there a way I can change my sessions#create function to look at the :user attribute and not :api_v1_user?

UPDATE

```
  namespace :api do
namespace :v1 do
    devise_for :users,
       path: '',
       path_names: {
         sign_in: 'login',
         sign_out: 'logout',
         registration: 'signup'
       },
       controllers: {
         sessions: 'api/v1/sessions',
         registrations: 'api/v1/registrations'
       }
```

Comment: can you share your routes ?

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. It feels hacky, but it works. Here is what I changed my Api::V1::SessionsController create method to:

```
  def create
    # Changing scope from :api_v1_user to :user
    Devise.mappings[:user] = Devise.mappings[:api_v1_user]
    warden.config[:default_strategies][:user] =  warden.config[:default_strategies].delete(:api_v1_user)
    auth_opts = auth_options
    auth_opts[:scope] = :user

    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_opts)

    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?

    render json: current_api_v1_user
  end
```

Comment: *Thank you*. I've been trying to fix this issue for two days and getting nowhere!

Comment: any ideas on how to resolve NoMethodError (undefined method `jwt_subject' for :api_v1_user:Symbol):?